# Volumetric lighting in Eevee goes through mesh

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

I created a fog in my scene to get the beam of my light in Eevee. I deactivated the shadow produced by the lustre mesh so as not to break my lighting. This option active or not, my light passes through my mesh. Do you have any idea where this might come from?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In eevee go to your volumetrics tab and crank up samples and light clamp.
[image]

BEFORE:

[image]

AFTER:

[image]

Comment: The volumetric shadow makes my light disappear. I can play with the sample, clamping etc ... but nothing happens.

Comment: play with the position of the light also. place it lower maybe

Comment: I tried but nothing happen. Should i do another post for that other problem ?

Comment: if it's working fine without the volumetric shadow, yes. I still think some geometry is blocking the light though. try to make all the shaders used in the lamp to have no shadows in the eevee option. just change shadow mode from opaque to none.

Comment: It’s already done. I tried to put the light down, but nothing happens. When the volumetric shadow is activated the lighting works but I lose the light beam.

Comment: I know this is old but i tried what you said, Mobin and even turning light clamp up to .001 makes all my rays and volumetric light disappear

Comment: leave clamp as 0, bump up the samples till you get none (the cap is 256 I think). for me on blender 3.0 on 256 samples I get no issues. also as I said where you put your light is important. preferably don't let the light touch inside of mesh or some distance near it.